# What is the probability of the sum of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$ to be multiplicatively inverted?

Tags: probability, number-theory

Given a set of elements $ x_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$ how can we express the probability of $\sum{(x_i)}^{-1}$ to have a multiplicative inverse $\mod \mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$, , where $N=pq$ for two safe prime numbers?

Comment: [Also asked simultaneously on crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24707/819)

Comment: How do we choose (i.e. with respect to which probability distribution) do we choose a random set of invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}$?

Comment: If we take a random subset of $k$ invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}$ and $k$ is big (say $k\gg \log^2 N$), it is reasonable to expect that the representation function for the associated sumset is almost equidistributed over $\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}$, giving that our probabilty is expected to be around $\frac{\varphi(N^2)}{N^2}=\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{q}\right).$